# Copy to Excel 2013 creating extra strings

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a piece of code that runs in outlook. The code runs through the body of email and copies specific words into Excel cells.

The code works just fine in Office 2010, but when i use the code in Office 2013 the words has extra strings copied to excel cells.

```
Private Sub deffolder_Click()
Unload Me
    Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
    Dim oAccount As Outlook.Account
    Dim fqdn() As String, host() As String, server() As String, y As Long
    Dim si() As String, ar() As String, ur() As String, emoc As String
    Dim xlapp As Object ' Excel.Application
    Dim xlwkb As Object ' Excel.Workbook
    Dim folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, ns As Outlook.NameSpace, tempfol
    Dim item As Object
    ReDim Preserve ar(n)
    ReDim Preserve ur(n)
    Dim trigger As String
    n = 0
    X = 0
    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")

For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts
    If oAccount = "example@email.com" Then
    Set folder = oAccount.DeliveryStore.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
start:
If folder.Items.Count > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Copying Servers from emails..", vbInformation, "Info"
    Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") ' New Excel.Application
    Set xlwkb = xlapp.Workbooks.Add
    For Each item In folder.Items
    'Set Sender = item.Sender
        If item.Subject Like "test" And item.Sender Like "Tested*" Then
            fqdn() = Split(Replace(item.body, "VM IP", "VM Name: "), "VM Name: ")
            fqdn(1) = Replace(fqdn(1), vbNewLine, vbNullString)
            X = X + 1
            'Writing Values in Excel Sheet for Servers from Cloud Emails
            xlapp.Cells(X, "A") = fqdn(1)                
            xlapp.Cells.wraptext = False
        End If
End if
  End if
Next
```

The cell value in excel has "expected output" and "*" and "tabspace" included. Any Suggestions/ideas?

By using fqdn(1) = Replace(fqdn(1), "*", vbNullString), i'm able to replace the "astriex" but unable to replace the "tab space" using same method. And in the first place what has caused issue in "office 2013", I wonder!

Comment: The cell value in excel has "expected output" and "*" and "tabspace" included. Any Suggestions/ideas?

Comment: By using fqdn(1) = Replace(fqdn(1), "*", vbNullString), i'm able to replace the "astriex" but unable to replace the "tab space" using same method.  And in the first place what has caused issue in "office 2013", I wonder.

Comment: Please edit your comments to the question

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a chance to look at the HTML markup of Outlook messages? Are there any difference?

Anyway, you use the Split function to remove additional whitespace, if any. Or just use the Word object model instead.

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx) - a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) - a string representing the HTML body of the specified item.
3. [Word editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) - the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. The WordEditor property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class from the Word object model which you can use to set up the message body.

You can read more about all these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx). It us up to you which way is to choose to deal with the message body.

Comment: First, i used simple body of the item to extract the information. Second, it is working fine with outlook 2010 but not with 2013. What's changed in these two versions?